# CMake Header Generator Updates

Tags: cmake

In CMake I currently have a simple Python script to generate a header, but if I update the script itself CMake won't re-run the script. Is there a way I can get CMake to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are directly invoking your code generation script when cmake is run. While it is possible solution but it is definitely not a right way to use code generators with cmake.

I recommend you to use `add_custom_command` for your case:

```
add_custom_command(
   OUTPUT generated.h
   COMMAND ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE} generator.py
   DEPENDS generator.py
   )
```

And next you can simple put your header to the list of source files passed to `add_library`/`add_executable` commands. cmake will automatically track all the dependencies and invoke your script.

Term `DEPENDS generator.py` informs cmake that it should regenerate header if script is changed.

With this approach file `generated.h` will be generated only at build time (when you run `make` or execute a build command in IDE). In contrast if you are running your script at cmake time (with `execute_process` command) then you have to rerun cmake to regenerate your file. Which is possible but you need to use some tricks to introduce a non-standard dependency.